# How to write a roslyn analyzer that references a dotnet standard 2.0 project

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn, xunit, .net-standard-2.0

I have the following error from my Roslyn analyzer test case from the following project

https://github.com/Weingartner/Migrations.Json.Net

> Expected collection to be empty, but found {Test0.cs(5,2): error
>   CS0012: The type 'Attribute' is defined in an assembly that is not
>   referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard,
>   Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.}.

The current metadata references in [DiagnosticVerifier.Helper.cs](https://github.com/Weingartner/Migrations.Json.Net/blob/63686b00a83ca50cf6c1702e998b47520ac90022/Weingartner.Json.Migration.Roslyn.Spec/Helpers/DiagnosticVerifier.Helper.cs) are

```
private static readonly MetadataReference CorlibReference = MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(object).Assembly.Location);
private static readonly MetadataReference SystemReference = MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(System.Uri).Assembly.Location);
private static readonly MetadataReference SystemCoreReference = MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(Enumerable).Assembly.Location);
private static readonly MetadataReference CSharpSymbolsReference = MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(CSharpCompilation).Assembly.Location);
private static readonly MetadataReference CodeAnalysisReference = MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(Compilation).Assembly.Location);
private static readonly MetadataReference SystemRuntimeReference = MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(Assembly.Load("System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a").Location);
private static readonly MetadataReference MigrationReference = MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(MigratableAttribute).Assembly.Location);
private static readonly MetadataReference SerializationReference = MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(DataMemberAttribute).Assembly.Location);
private static readonly MetadataReference JsonNetReference = MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert).Assembly.Location);
```

One of the references

```
private static readonly MetadataReference MigrationReference =
    MetadataReference
      .CreateFromFile(typeof(MigratableAttribute).Assembly.Location);
```

refers to a subproject **Weingartner.Json.Migration**

[image]

this project is a dotnetstandard 2.0 project

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <RootNamespace>Weingartner.Json.Migration</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>Weingartner.Json.Migration</AssemblyName>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="10.0.3" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Weingartner.Json.Migration.Common_\Weingartner.Json.Migration.Common.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

However when I run the analyzer test case I get the runtime error that I should reference **netstandard**

> Expected collection to be empty, but found {Test0.cs(5,2): error
>   CS0012: The type 'Attribute' is defined in an assembly that is not
>   referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard,
>   Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.}. 
>   at FluentAssertions.Execution.XUnit2TestFramework.Throw(String
>   message)    at
>   FluentAssertions.Execution.AssertionScope.FailWith(String message,
>   Object[] args)    at
>   FluentAssertions.Execution.GivenSelector`1.FailWith(String message,
>   Object[] args)    at
>   FluentAssertions.Collections.CollectionAssertions`2.BeEmpty(String
>   because, Object[] becauseArgs)    at
>   TestHelper.DiagnosticVerifier.CreateProject(String[] sources, String
>   language)    at TestHelper.DiagnosticVerifier.GetDocuments(String[]
>   sources, String language)    at
>   TestHelper.DiagnosticVerifier.GetSortedDiagnostics(String[] sources,
>   String language, DiagnosticAnalyzer analyzer)    at
>   TestHelper.DiagnosticVerifier.VerifyDiagnostics(String[] sources,
>   String language, DiagnosticAnalyzer analyzer, DiagnosticResult[]
>   expected)    at
>   TestHelper.DiagnosticVerifier.VerifyCSharpDiagnostic(String source,
>   DiagnosticResult[] expected)    at
>   Weingartner.Json.Migration.Roslyn.Spec.DataContractAnalyzerSpec.ShouldCreateDiagnosticIfMigratableTypeDoesntHaveDataContractAttributeSet()

My guess is I'm missing something at the point I create the project. I can't see an API to specify which version of the framework I'm targeting but the API is quite large so maybe I've missed something.

```
    private static Project CreateProject(string[] sources, string language = LanguageNames.CSharp)
    {
        string fileNamePrefix = DefaultFilePathPrefix;
        string fileExt = language == LanguageNames.CSharp ? CSharpDefaultFileExt : VisualBasicDefaultExt;

        var projectId = ProjectId.CreateNewId(debugName: TestProjectName);

        var solution = new AdhocWorkspace()
            .CurrentSolution
            .AddProject(projectId, TestProjectName, TestProjectName, language)
            .AddMetadataReference(projectId, CorlibReference)
            .AddMetadataReference(projectId, SystemReference)
            .AddMetadataReference(projectId, SystemCoreReference)
            .AddMetadataReference(projectId, CSharpSymbolsReference)
            .AddMetadataReference(projectId, CodeAnalysisReference)
            .AddMetadataReference(projectId, SystemRuntimeReference)
            .AddMetadataReference(projectId, MigrationReference)
            .AddMetadataReference(projectId, SerializationReference)
            .AddMetadataReference(projectId, JsonNetReference);
        var compilationOptions = solution
            .GetProject(projectId)
            .CompilationOptions
            .WithOutputKind(OutputKind.DynamicallyLinkedLibrary);
        solution = solution
            .WithProjectCompilationOptions(projectId, compilationOptions);

        int count = 0;
        foreach (var source in sources)
        {
            var newFileName = fileNamePrefix + count + "." + fileExt;
            var documentId = DocumentId.CreateNewId(projectId, debugName: newFileName);
            solution = solution.AddDocument(documentId, newFileName, SourceText.From(source));
            count++;
        }
        var project = solution.GetProject(projectId);
        var diangostics = project.GetCompilationAsync().Result.GetDiagnostics();
        diangostics.Should().BeEmpty();
        return project;
    }
```

Answer (score 20):

Turns out the answer was as obvious as the error message. Just a reference to netstandard.

```
diff --git a/Weingartner.Json.Migration.Roslyn.Spec/Helpers/DiagnosticVerifier.Helper.cs b/Weingartner.Json.Migration.Roslyn.Spec/Helpers/DiagnosticVerifier.Helper.cs
index da3b933..ba6cc7c 100644
--- a/Weingartner.Json.Migration.Roslyn.Spec/Helpers/DiagnosticVerifier.Helper.cs
+++ b/Weingartner.Json.Migration.Roslyn.Spec/Helpers/DiagnosticVerifier.Helper.cs
@@ -28,6 +28,7 @@ namespace TestHelper
         private static readonly MetadataReference CSharpSymbolsReference = MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(CSharpCompilation).Assembly.Location);
         private static readonly MetadataReference CodeAnalysisReference = MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(Compilation).Assembly.Location);
         private static readonly MetadataReference SystemRuntimeReference = MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(Assembly.Load("System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a").Location);
+        private static readonly MetadataReference NetStandard = MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(Assembly.Load("netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0").Location);
         private static readonly MetadataReference MigrationReference = MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(MigratableAttribute).Assembly.Location);
         private static readonly MetadataReference SerializationReference = MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(DataMemberAttribute).Assembly.Location);
         private static readonly MetadataReference JsonNetReference = MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert).Assembly.Location);
@@ -169,6 +170,7 @@ namespace TestHelper
                 .AddMetadataReference(projectId, SystemRuntimeReference)
                 .AddMetadataReference(projectId, MigrationReference)
                 .AddMetadataReference(projectId, SerializationReference)
+                .AddMetadataReference(projectId, NetStandard)
                 .AddMetadataReference(projectId, JsonNetReference);
             var compilationOptions = solution
                 .GetProject(projectId)
```